# Show .dat file (which is UTF8) in GitExtensions

Tags: git, git-extensions

GitExtensions seems to have a "feature" which decides that *.dat files are only shown as binary in the "File Tree" tab.

I have got some *.dat files which are UTF8 encoded text and I must stick to their name pattern. If I rename them to any other file ending, their content can be displayed.

Note: the diff view does work within GitExtensions. Also, the file can be displayed via git bash "git show :myfile.dat"

Is it possible to make GitExtensions show *.dat files in the "File Tree" tab?

Comment: Can you diff the files with git bash, or is the problem only in GitExtensions? If the problem also exists in git bash, it can be solved with `.gitattributes`

Comment: @1615903: okay, in git bash everything works fine, so this must be a Git-Extension thing. Also, now I saw that diffing also works in GitExtensions. Only the file display via "File Tree" tab does not show the file's content.

Comment: Just say "text file" not `UTF8 encoded`. There is no difference between ASCII file and UTF8 for latin characters. If your file contains English text, these are essentially ASCII text files with a `.dat` extension

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: correct, but if you search for "git treats text as binary" you will find heaps of people trying to display UTF16 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was [a bug](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/commit/f4ffe53b92fdc1a48b8d79377899ae8d87280e2e) in GitExtensions while obtaining data from .gitattributes.
You can download a fixed version from [here](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/releases/tag/v2.50RC2). 
You should also add the following line to your .gitattributes file in order to tell that `dat` files should be treated as text files:

`*.dat      text`